# Retrieve JSON Data with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Im trying to retrieve some data from JSON object which holds location information such as streetname, postcode etc. But nothing is being retrieved when i try and put it in my div. Can anybody see where im going wrong with this?

This is my ajax code to request and retrieve the data

```
var criterion = document.getElementById("address").value;
$.ajax({
          url: 'process.php',
          type: 'GET',
          data: 'address='+ criterion,
          success: function(data) 
          {
              $('#txtHint').html(data);
              $.each(data, function(i,value)
                {
                    var str = "Postcode: ";
                    str += value.postcode;
                    $('#txtHint').html(str);
                });
            //alert("Postcode: " + data.postcode);
          },
          error: function(e) 
          {
            //called when there is an error
            console.log(e.message);
            alert("error");
          }
});
```

When this is run in the broswer is just says "Postcode: undefined".

This is the php code to select the data from the database.

```
    $sql="SELECT * FROM carparktest WHERE postcode LIKE '".$search."%'";


$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) $rows[] = $r;
echo json_encode($rows), "\n"; //Puts each row onto a new line in the json data
```

Comment: `data: 'address='+ criterion,` can easily be changed to `data: { address: criterion }`, makes it simpler to add more.

Comment: What errors show up in your Firebug, PHP, and MySQL logs?

Comment: additionally, since you're using JQuery - you can replace getElementById simply with $("#address")

Comment: Also - a top AJAX tip is to open the target URL directly in a browser first to make sure that works, and then you know if the fault lies in fetching the result, or interpreting it.

Comment: Try giving the url to your page, so we can take a look at the JS console output for ourselves.

Comment: When i just display the 'data'in the txtint div it displays all of the information like this [{"name":"carpark1","street":"high street","postcode":"de224bt","type":"long stay","long":"23","lat":"12"} i just need to extract parts of it such as the postcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the data type:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'json'
})
```

You can use also the [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

**EDIT: example of JSON**

```
$.getJSON('process.php', { address: criterion } function(data) {
    //do what you need with the data
    alert(data);
}).error(function() { alert("error"); });
```

Comment: Im a bit confused as to how i would change it to .getJSON

Comment: Ok, i put an example of getJSON.

Comment: Thanks, ive jsut tried using that code and displaying all of the object as i did before and nothing appeared in my div. I tried this

$.getJSON('process.php', 
 { address: criterion }, function(data) 
 {
    //do what you need with the data
    $('#txtHint').html(data);
 }).error(function() { alert("error"); });

Comment: Also when i enter the dataType:'json' nothing displays now.

Comment: The return is a json, not a html so you cannot just call `.html()`. If you alert the data, what appears?

Answer (score 1):

Just look at what your code is doing.

First, put the data directly into the `#txtHint` box.

Then, for each data element, create the string `"Postcode: "+value.postcode` (without even checking if `value.postcode` exists - it probably doesn't) and overwrite the html in `#txtHint` with it.

End result: the script is doing exactly what you told it to do.

Remove that loop thing, and see what you get.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would i check if there is somthing in value.postcode?

Answer (score 0):

Does your JSON data represent multiple rows containing the same object structure? Please alert the data object in your success function and post it so we can help you debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the

```
dataType: 'json'
```

param in your ajax call
or use [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) Which will automatically convert JSON data into a JS object.

You can also convert the JSON response into JS object yourself using [$.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) inside success callback like this

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me on your site:

```
function showCarPark(){
    var criterion = $('#address').val();

    // Assuming this does something, it's yours ;)
    codeAddress(criterion);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'process.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            address: criterion
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
            $("#txtHint").html("");
            $.each(data, function(k,v)
            {
                $("#txtHint").append("Postcode: " + v.postcode + "<br/>");
            });
        },
        error: function(e)
        {
            alert(e.message);
        }

    });
}
```